# Mysql, select row on a max condition and show associated columns

Tags: mysql

I have

```
select max(id), timestamp from mytable;
```

This returned the max-id over the data, but the timestamp doesn't seem to be the one matching the row. I got

```
+----------+--------------------------+
| max(id) | from_unixtime(timestamp) |
+----------+--------------------------+
|  1429517 | 2015-01-01 00:00:15      |
+----------+--------------------------+
```

This is the correct max-id, but the timestamp belongs to a different record

Comment: You want the timestamp that is referent to the max id?

Comment: yes, I want the timestamp that belongs to the record with the max id

Comment: @Rahul have answered the way you need to do! He was faster than me xD

Comment: yea that worked, but kind of surprised that it can't be done in just one select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
SELECT id, timestamp FROM mytable
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable)
```

ie get the `max(id)` using a subquery and then get the corresponding data from the table.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT id, timestamp
FROM mytable
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This should be quite efficient with an index on `id` or `id`/`timestamp`.

Comment: I like this answer because wondering if it could be done using only one select

Comment: Although maybe need DESC in there? `SELECT id, timestamp FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` otherwise seemed to get the min value

Comment: @area5one:- Yes you need to have DESC else it would be by default ASC and give you the min result.